# How to achieve uniform hash rate

Tags: mining, hashrate, ubuntu

I am trying to learn about mining and am using xmr-stak-cpu on Ubuntu 17.10 to mine with an AMD a10 6800k processor. I haven't seen a single time my miner reporting 100H/s but the stats of my miner on the pool say I have been at that rate for some time. How can I reach this hash rate more often?

Also I tried to use iGPU to mine but the xmr stak miner does not identify it, is it a driver problem since ubuntu 17.10 does not have proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 6):

Pools do not know your hash rate, they can only estimate it based on the shares you submit. Since finding those shares is in inherently random process, you will sometimes have lucky breaks, and sometimes long dry spells. This will translate to a randomly changing hash rate being reported by the pool. Your miner knows the rate at which it is hashing, so reports the actual rate.

Comment: Also the maximum hashrate of my cpu is around 198#/s how could i achieve this

Answer (score -1):

Try setting to 2 threads in the config file to get better performance